# How to use OpenCV to do OCR and text detect and recognition

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, computer-vision, google-colaboratory, ocr

I am working on a test application to develop a small text detection and recognition app in python using Google Collab. Can you advise any code examples to achieve this? My requirement is that I should be able to detect and recognize text in an image using OpenCV.

Please advise.

Comment: You could try EAST detector. Docs aren't great, but there is some information [here](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/d1e/tutorial_dnn_OCR.html) and a tutorial is [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/). If you are willing to consider something outside OpenCV, you can look at [pytesseract](https://github.com/madmaze/pytesseract)

Comment: Thanks bfris. I will explore EAST as well. Can OpenCV do text detection and recognition on its own or it needs some other OCR support for the purpose? Sorry for the simple question, but I have just started exploring this domain

Comment: I haven't done much with EAST, but I think it doesn't have any other dependencies besides OpenCV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to make pipeline with following step. if you work only opencv.

- opencv for pre-processing - use morphological operations.
- For Text detection - use Craft model or finding contours in your image.
- For Recognition - Use Tesseract-OCR

According to my personal experience. [EasyOCR](https://github.com/JaidedAI/EasyOCR) is very good with good accuracy. easy to use and train your own text also.

Comment: Thanks Faisal. I have tried EasyOCR. It is good, But I am looking to achieve OCR with purely OpenCV. Does OpenCV offer text recognition API methods like we have in EasyOCR or Tesseract ?

Comment: but craft can be too slow